# Java Runnable using a utility function post call

Tags: java, multithreading, jenkins, javax, javax.ws.rs

I have a work project where I am having multiple threads call a utility function I created that sends a post form to an internal API we have.

I use the `callAPI` method here which is in a utility class, which is public, final and static :

```
public static  int callAPI(String url, TaskListener listener, String operation, String id, String password, String sUser){
      Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();



      Form form = new Form();
      form.param("case", id);
      form.param("user", sUser);
      form.param("password", password);
      listener.getLogger().println("*******************************************************");
      listener.getLogger().println("Sending API Service Request");

      Response response = client.target(url)
              .path(operation)
              .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
              .post(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE));


  }
```

I then have this run method in my Runnable class:

```
  @Override
  public void run(){

       listener.getLogger().println("Thread Started.\n");

       int runId = Utility.callAPI(wUrl, listener, operation, password, sUser);

       listener.getLogger().println("call completed");
  }
```

So what actually prints in Jenkins console output:

```
*******************************************************
Sending API Service Request
Thread Started.
```

This means I know my `run()` method is being called and so my thread is starting. I know it can see my `runAPI` method in the utility.

Now all I can gather is that this line:

```
 Response response = client.target(url)
                  .path(operation)
                  .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                  .post(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE));
```

sends a request and from there the thread exits before it finishes off the rest of the `run()` method.

I've tried:

- putting a thread sleep loop
- putting the call in a while loop

It has been awhile since I've done any Java programming or threading. This is something very simple that I know I am forgetting.

> ALSO I HAVE CHANGED A LOT OF MY CODE AND HAVE ONLY SHOWN THE CRITICAL PARTS BEING THIS IS PART OF A WORK PROJECT AND I DIDNT WANT TO TAKE CHANCES.

Comment: Have you tried waiting for the thread to finish by running `thread.join()`? (after you run `thread.start()`)

Comment: It's probably throwing an exception. Try putting a try catch in there.

Comment: @A.Pahlavan I'm actually using Jenkins Executor service, and not starting threads in that style. I can see if it has some relatable.

Comment: @RobinGreen an exception in the Response line? I'll try a catch there I know the thread is def running however I can also figure out how to catch exceptions with my executor service if need be.

Comment: Have you tried to debug this code?  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: yes I have tried to debug this code. I don't use Eclipse.

Comment: @KyleCalica-St I m using Jenkins version : 2.164.3. I want to call Jenkins REST API to create a JOb by passing job name and config.xml. How to implement this in Java. Please post some code as an example to implement this.